# lavfi virtual device - the same parameters for ffmpeg and ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg

The command

```
ffplay -f lavfi -graph testsrc2=d=1[out0];sine=d=1[out1] test.mp4
```

works fine. But the same arguments for `ffmpeg` (instead of `ffplay`)

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -graph testsrc2=d=1[out0];sine=d=1[out1] test.mp4
```

produce only the error

> ```
> [NULL @ 00000000006934c0] Requested output format 'lavfi' is not a suitable output format
> test.mp4: Invalid argument
> ```

What's wrong with it?

---

*Note:*

From the [FFmpeg documentation for the lavfi](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#lavfi):

> Currently only video data is supported.

It seems that's not true nowadays, at least `ffplay` works fine with audio (see my first command).
Or I incorrectly interpret this sentence?

But just in case I tried using the filtergraph `testsrc2=d=1[out0];testsrc=d=1[out1]` instead, with the same results — `ffplay` — OK, `ffmpeg` — the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ffmpeg tool can work with multiple inputs and outputs so the parser looks for `-i` to demarcate input options. The lavfi device will read the graph from the input argument

Use

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "testsrc2=d=1[out0];sine=d=1[out1]" test.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, I new this — IMHO — workaround. The base of my question was a little other (my flaw for not state it clearly) — *is the documentation for `lavfi` inappropriate / incomplete / obsolete?* Is the parser for the `ffmpeg` command *different* from the one for `ffplay` (for the `lavfi` device)?

Comment: Yes, ffmpeg, ffplay and ffprobe each has its own parser. The lavfi device is a component within the libavdevice library which may be used by other frontends, so the interface will depend on the frontend.